# C# Get all items that has a common property

Tags: c#, linq

This should be fairly simple, but I'm having a really headache, I think I need some sleep.

I have a List from some code

The property object is like :

```
public class Properties {
    public int IdProperty 
    public int ProductId
}
```

This is much as a KeyValue pair. With example this values:

```
Product - Property
1          1
1          2
2          1
2          3
3          1
3          3
```

What I want is to get, from that list, the properties that has all products (in this case, properties with id 1)

the return list should be:

```
1           1
2           1
3           1
```

this should be really simple, isnt it ? (trying it using lambda linq)

**Added tryed queries:**

```
properties.Where(p => properties.All(x => x.IdProperty == p.IdProperty));
properties.Join(properties, p=>p.IdProperty, ... not sure what to put on other params);
```

some crazy 2 way lists to match.

**note:** I don't know the common property.

Comment: You should show queries you've tried.

Comment: added. they are not working so I don't think have any value but to prove I'm at least trying something. This is getting no where in SO in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return properties.Where(p => p.PropertyId == 1);
```

Where `properties` is an `IEnumerable<Properties>` containing the property objects you want to select from.

**EDIT**
Now understanding your question, one way to get all property ids common to all products would be:

```
var productCount = properties.Select(p => p.ProductId).Distinct().Count();
return properties.Where(p => properties.Count(x => x.IdProperty == p.IdProperty) == productCount);
```

Comment: I don't know the common property.

Comment: I don't think he knows the property which will be common for all ;)

Comment: Right, I misunderstood the question. Let me adjust it.

Comment: Distinct doesn't have a func as first parameter (am I missing something) ? also it won't return an int but a IEnumerable<Property> so you cannot equals Count (int) to it.

Comment: @Bart Fixed, I forgot that `Distinct` doesn't have a key selector.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you don't know which property is common to all products...

```
// get number of products
var nbOfProducts = properties.Select(x => x.Product).Distinct().Count();

// group records by property
// and get only groups with number of items same as number of products
var result = properties.GroupBy(x => x.Property)
                       .Where(g => g.Count() == nbOfProducts)
                       .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yourCollection.Where(p => p.PropertyId == 1);
```

or

```
yourCollection.GroupBy(p => p.PropertyId);
```

This 2nd option will group them so that you can get other ones if you need them.

Comment: I don't know the common property.